# Swift numbered function arguments

Tags: swift, function, arguments, closures

Recently, I came across the `map` function in Swift which uses numbered parameters, like so: `values.map { $0 * $0 }`.

I was wondering, how does this work internally exactly? How could I write my own function which can receive numbered parameters?

Comment: Look for "shorthand parameters" in the "Closures" chapter of the Swift reference.

Comment: Great, it all makes sense now, thanks!

Comment: In the Swift 3/Swift 4 version of the Swift reference the section is named "Shorthand Argument Names". I found it by searching on `$0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are called "Anonymous Closure Arguments" or "Shorthand Argument Names". They only work for closures, not functions.